# Client Applications losing Db Connectivity

Tags: sql-server

I am a Support technician for an Application using a 2008 SQL Server Express database and the our client app-installations occasionally loses connection to the SQL Server database.

Note: I am a total beginner with SQL and unfortunately our company no longer has an application Eng.

So where to begin? Our customers usually have a few client applications installed (say 2 to 10) and for the most part the application will connect to the server's DB without error. Then all of a sudden we fail to connect, usually with a simple "Unable to connect to the database" error. 
Interestingly, in most cases they can wait 30+mins and the problem goes away.

We have the Named Pipes and TCP/IP enabled for remote connections. Any suggestions to consider?

Comment: That could be anything from too many open connections, which could happen with a poorly written app, to a network switch (hardware) problem. Start by investigating the users pc when it happens  and look at error messages, event logs, connections, time stamps to compare on the server or hardware etc. That is probably the only advice you will get with this question, its just way too broad with too little detail.

Comment: It's a tough one, as you mentioned "too broad" and the issue comes and goes! Thanks!

Comment: Is "Unable to connect to the database" an application specific error? Often applications capture useful error messages and turn them into useless error messages like this. To troubleshoot you will need to capture this in flight and undertake some analysis. This has a great guide: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sql_protocols/2008/04/30/steps-to-troubleshoot-sql-connectivity-issues/ For example after a bit of analysis you'll be able to run the network level checks and rules that in or out

Comment: The other thing you can do from the other side is check the sql server error logs and see if there are any useful messages in there. The fact that it is intermittent might point to a capacity issue on the SQL Server. To troubleshoot any issue you need to break it into pieces and isoliate the piece that is the issue. If you can confirm network connectivity then you can rule that out and move on to investigating the SQL Server

Comment: Please don't deface your question by rolling back our improvements.